# Force Doctrine to create type="guid" as VARCHAR(255) instead of CHAR(36)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to add a new entity to my Symfony project that uses `GUID` field to map to another Entity:

```
// OtherEntity

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="guid", type="guid", unique=true)
 */
protected $guid;


// New Entity

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OtherEntity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="other_guid", referencedColumnName="guid", nullable=false, onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $otherEntity;
```

Doctrine dumps the following SQL staments to create the table for the `NewEntity` when using `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE new_entity (guid CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', other_guid CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', ...

ALTER TABLE new_entity ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D3D1CD16A7FC4818 FOREIGN KEY (other_guid) REFERENCES other_entity (guid) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

When running `doctrine:schema:update --force` instead, I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                                                                                     
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE new_entity ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D3D1CD16A7FC4818 FOREIGN KEY (other_guid) REFERENCES other_entity (guid) ON DELETE SET NULL':  
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

After some digging I found, that `type="guid"`being translated to `CHAR(36)` is the problem. If `VARCHAR(255)` is used instead, everything works fine.

The problem is, that the `guid` field of the `other_entity` table is `VARCHAR(255)`. Thus the `CHAR(36)` field in `new_entity` cannot be mapped to a field of another type.

I have recently updated my Symfony project:

```
doctrine/dbal               v2.4.4  --> 2.5.5
doctrine/doctrine-bundle    v1.2.0  --> 1.6.2           
doctrine/orm                v2.4.8  --> 2.5.5
symfony/symfony             v2.7.7  --> v2.8.12
```

**Running `doctrine:schema:update` under the old config, the `GUID` fields are created as `VARCHAR(255)` while the new config creates them as `CHAR(36)`.**

Using `CHAR(36)` makes sense, since this is the length of GUIDs. But the new format brings up the problem described before: Mappings to old fields of the same type (guid) are not possible any more.

I do not understand, why `doctrine:schema:update` does not update the existing fields to the new format as well.

**Is there anything I can do do either force Doctrine to update all existing fields to `CHAR(36)` or to keep creating `GUID` as `VARCHAR(255)`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the same length for the related fields and add `options={"fixed" = true}`